# Remove duplication between staging.rb and production.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a staging and production environment for my Rails application (running on Heroku). At the moment, there is a lot of stuff in staging.rb and production.rb that I'm having to define separately in each file, e.g.:

```
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true
```

This is not `DRY`. Is there an elegant way that I can effectively import the settings from production.rb into staging.rb and then just override the settings which I wish to change for the staging environment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What I've done in the past is have a file that contains the shared settings and then require this in the production and staging environment files. This has worked well because it allows you to define the common settings in one place, and then define the unique settings in the individual files:

**config/environments/shared_production.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
end
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
require Rails.root.join('config/environments/shared_production')

MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :logger

  # Url to be used in mailer links
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "production.com" }
end
```

**config/environments/staging.rb**

```
require Rails.root.join('config/environments/shared_production')

MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Url to be used in mailer links
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mysite-dev.com" }
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. =) Gracias!

Comment: With ruby 1.9+ you can use require_relative.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is how good it gets.  those are configuration settings and are meant to be set individually.  You can actually define a function to pass in the config.  On that function, you can set a default but I wouldn't want to do this.  In a lifecycle of a project, you only work with less than 5 (or 10) environments so you need at most 10 of these files which you wont be editing all the time.